# Build ubuntu from source code cd

Tags: compiling

This is a very theoretical question and I am not in the need to actually do this, but I find the question still highly interesting
Ubuntu offers source code cd downloads:

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04/release/source/

I was always wondering, if this is could be really useful for someone wanting to compile the whole os from scratch. I know that may surely not be the idea of this offer, but is there any systematic way to auto build the whole distribution, or is this simply only a collection of the sources of all default installed packages?
What about build deps of source packages and build deps of build deps?

Is there after all a tool that would automate building ubuntu from such a source cd?

Answer (score 0):

> source code cd downloads

No, the source isn't available on a CD. I doubt it would fit on a CD (700MB).

> but is there any systematic way to auto build the whole distribution, or is this simply only a collection of the sources of all default installed packages?

[This page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile) describes how to build the OS from source. In general, you would clone the [Git repo](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Dev/KernelGitGuide?action=show&redirect=KernelTeam%2FKernelGitGuide#Kernel.2BAC8-Action.2BAC8-GitTheSource.Obtaining_the_kernel_sources_for_an_Ubuntu_release_using_git) and then use autotools to build the kernel.

> What about build deps of source packages and build deps of build deps?

This is what package managers (apt, yum) are designed to resolve.

If you're interested in learning more about this I suggest checking out [Linux from Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/).

Comment: The things is indeed called "source cd", even if it does not fit on a cd, see the link. I am not interested in building the kernel, as I do that regularly without problems. I think you misunderstood the question.

Comment: I honestly don't mean this to be insulting, but is English your first language? The question is very fragmented. Perhaps taking the time to write a more clear question (I'll help if you need it) would attract answers more to your liking. Also, note the [docs on when to down-vote](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down): "Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect."